# Can I view tags from my profile without my account attached to the search?

Tags: feature-request, tags, profile-page

On the profile window, near my reputation it shows my top tag. When I click on it, it takes me to the MySQL questions and also has my user number in the search criteria. The same happens when I click any tags in the tags section.

Because I browse this tag a lot for answers to give, it would be nice to be able to access it right from my profile (since it is always just one click away). Unfortunately, I either have to type the tag into the search bar, or click on a question/answer I gave and click on the tag from there. If I click the tag from my profile, I have to remove the user part and search again.

Is there any way we can make the tags (or at least the top tag) on our profiles link to the tab page themselves?

For clarification, instead of clicking on a tag taking me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:3131147%20[mysql]), I want it to take me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql).

Comment: @Kendra Yes, I knew that, I will add that in there too, thanks for reminding me. Not the worst thing in the world, but a bit of a nuisance IMHO.

Comment: Third way, click on the tag on your profile, then click on the tag in the side-bar summarizing the active search. Anyway, I'm against changing things, as it's more useful as-is both on one's own and other peoples profiles.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags

Comment: I know where to find the tags, but I'm looking for a way to access specific ones from my profile, without having to go look at all tags.

Comment: Rather than trying to reduce the steps to get from your profile page to a list of Q to answer, why not reduce steps even farther? When you're in the mood to look for places to share knowledge, just click on a bookmark in your browser, and go straight to the list. Ad this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) to your bookmarks/favorites bar and it's all ready for instant access.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a device with a mouse you can hover over the tag and select the "info" link.

You will then need one more click to get on to the newest questions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While I've found this annoying, I'm typically on the homepage filtered by my favorite tag(s) so it isn't an issue for me *often*. Probably not often enough to change how it works as it can be very handy if you *do want* to filter your posts by tag.

The simplest solution I've found, when on my profile page (or anyone's really) is...

1. If I've clicked through several things in my profile then I will
   click "Questions" at the top then my tag.
2. Otherwise, I just click the back button and refresh

Obviously, there are many other ways to get there but this is what seems the simplest/most logical for me in these situations.